# Playing music paused on live streaming begins : react-native-twilio-video-webrtc

Tags: android, ios, react-native, mobile, twilio

We are currently using Twilio for video live streaming using "react-native-twilio-video-webrtc" library.While we are able to successfully conduct live streaming without any issues, we have encounter a problem when music is playing (any music app) and user starts streaming the running music will paused. We want the music to play continuously when the user starts streaming. The same thing happens when the app is connected to the car it pauses the music and shows a message on the dashboard as image attached.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ttgAb.jpg)

We have also opened a question on the issue at https://github.com/blackuy/react-native-twilio-video-webrtc/issues/725

Version:

- "react-native-twilio-video-webrtc": "^3.2.0"
- Node.js: v20.5.0
- "react-native": "0.70.2"

I look into library code but didn't get anything.